# TARGET_OS_IOS, TARGET_OS_TV and simulators

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, tvos

I've "ported" an iOS App to Apple TV and since I really wanted to share as resources as possible I had to target some lines of code for iOS and some others to TVOS. 
I've tried with something like:

```
#if TARGET_OS_TV
```

and

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
```

but when I launch the apps on iOS or TV simulator this code doesn't work. I thought that iPhone simulator just executes the code under `TARGET_OS_IOS`... but I was wrong. Which is the best way to target iOS and TV os preserving simulators correct execution?

An example of the code that I might need is:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS 
    DoSomethingWithiOS() // This should work also on iOS sim
#elseif TARGET_OS_TV
    DoSomethingWithOSTV() // This should work also on TV sim
#endif
```

Comment: Well `TARGET_iOS` doesn't exist.  Can you post the actual code that isn't working?

Comment: @dan it was just a "typo". I fixed it.

Comment: You're still spelling it differently in both places.  Can you post the actual code that isn't working?

Comment: Added an example of code. I haven't got a full code since I saw that it wasn't working...

Comment: Just wanted to note that TARGET_OS_TV and TARGET_OS_IOS are correct. The OP seems to have fixed their example and the original typo is lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For someone looking for platform macro as me.

In ObjC use `TARGET_OS_IOS` for iOS and `TARGET_OS_TV` for tvOS as next:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS
    /// [something doIOS];
#elif TARGET_OS_TV
    /// [something doTVOS];
#else
    /// Perhaps watchOS or macOS?
#endif
```